# Pull data from URL in adjacent cell

Tags: excel, web-scraping, excel-formula

I am making a databse for language learning flashcards. I know bits of HTML and some code but have never used VBA. I have a list of ~1000 words and I want to add additional data (english definition, conjugations, etc., examples).

I know a website with all fo this and I do not want to go through every word and copy and paste the info into a spreadsheet. So I started putting together something like this:

| Words | URL |
| --- | --- |
| Eingang | ="https://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/?w="&A2 |
| einkaufen | ="https://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/?w="&A3 |

Now I want to add columns that pull data from the tables on the website linked. Any ideas?